# MySQL: SELECT row which meets criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a Table myTable with the Columns

```
id, foreignID, isDefault, textValue
```

Values could be something like

```
1, 1, 1, NULL
2, 1, 0, NULL
3, 1, 0, 'ABC'
4, 2, 1, 'DE'
5, 2, 0, 'AB'
6, 3, 1, NULL
6, 3, 0, 'DE'
```

I want to get ONE textValue for every foreignID where the textValue is not NULL.

If there are more then one textValues which are not NULL for the foreignID and one of those has "isDefault = 1) I want to select this one.

Any ideas? :)

(So I would like to get the rows number 3, 4 and 6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to get the entire row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by foreignId) as seqnum
      from myTable t
      where textValue is not null
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or if you just want `textValue`, use aggregation:

```
select foreignId, max(textValue)
from mytable
where textValue is not null
group by foreignId;
```

Comment: But how would I get the "isDefault" in my aggregation?
(If isDefault = 1 AND textValue IS NOT NULL I would want to get this textValue)

Comment: @TikTak . . . The first query returns `isDefault`.  Otherwise, that column is not mentioned in your question.  If you have a question concerning `isDefault` and can't figure out what to do (probably just filtering on the value), then ask a *new* question with a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way - by adding an order by clause in row_number()

```
select *
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by foreignId order by  isDefault desc) as rn      
      from tablename
      where textValue is not null
     ) A
where rn= 1
```